# Why does Backpack demo crash on Article create or edit

Tags: php, laravel-backpack

When I run the backpack demo locally on my machine, and I want to edit or add an **Article**, the following error occurs:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "SHOW": syntax error 
(SQL: SHOW COLUMNS FROM `articles` WHERE Field = "status")
```

This error does not happen on the online demo
https://demo.backpackforlaravel.com/admin/article/create or https://demo.backpackforlaravel.com/admin/article/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#enum-1

> PLEASE NOTE the enum field only works for MySQL databases.

When using SQLite, the solution is to change the `enum` type to a `select_from_array` type in the `ArticleCrudController`

```
 $this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'status',
    'label' => 'Status',
    // 'type' => 'enum', // not supported by SQLite
    'type' => 'select_from_array',
    'options'  => [
        'PUBLISHED' => 'PUBLISHED', 
        'DRAFT' => 'DRAFT',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: @tabacitu it would be nice to have an explicit `enum not supported by SQLite` error

Comment: @tabacitu, Is there a way to publish this file so that it is not overwritten at the next update?